# Is it possible to optimise index across mac Spotlight, QuickSilver, Eclipse and InstaSearch?

Tags: eclipse, macos, quicksilver

I am using Spotlight, QuickSilver, Eclipse and InstaSearch plugin for eclipse. Each of these modules have search capabilities.  I guess each of these modules may be using an index of its own and am wondering if it is possible to coerce all these / some of these applications to use a single index so that we can save CPU cycle time.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After significant research, I have come to to the conclusion that this is not possible.